# How to modify a system configuration file on Android?

Tags: android

On an Android device I would like to modify /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf with as minimal side effects to the rest of the device as possible. (there are unexposed APIs in Android framework)

Is it possible to just use a command line su executable to get permissions to modify the file?

Can I do this without an unlocked boot loader?

Would this be easier on a Nexus device?

Comment: try android.stackexchange.com

Comment: A stock android "su" won't work on behalf of ordinary users.  A hacked one would, but installing that is a different question.  Regardless, this sounds like you want to make a one-off manual modification, not write a program, and so it probably is off topic here.

Comment: Thanks, posted here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/65843/how-to-modify-a-system-configuration-file-on-android